# How can i determine the country code just by looking at the number

Tags: javascript, react-native, phone-number, country-codes

I'm Developing an app in react-native where i get phone numbers from the phones contact list. The problem here is many people save the number without country code in their phonebook. In such cases i'm unable to determine to which country that phone number is from. Does anyone has a solution for this ?

Here's an example:

Suppose i have number from India(+91) saved as 1111111111(10 digit number) but there is no country code prefix here. Now how should i determine country code for that number?

Comment: There is no solution. That's the reason for country codes to exist

Comment: Why do you use input masking?

Comment: _“The problem here is many people save the number without country code.”_ - well then implement proper validation that does not let them do that in the first place.

Comment: @04FS Contacts are being picked from the phonebook and not from my app

Comment: That should not stop you from implementing an additional step that asks them to edit the number accordingly, if your app determined it is in the wrong format?

Answer (score 3):

So if the country code is not provided in the phone number, you can not detect the country in any case.

If it is provided, you can filter the country from the below JSON with the function below:

```
const countries = JSONContent; // as below

function findCountry(code) {
    const i = 0;
    while(countries[i] && (countries[i].dial_code === code || countries[i].dial_code === '+' + code)) {
        i++;
    }
    if (countries[i]) {
        return countries[i].name; // Or countries[i].code, or the whole countries[i] object
    }
    return 'No country found';
}
```

JSON

```
[{"name":"Israel","dial_code":"+972","code":"IL"},{"name":"Afghanistan","dial_code":"+93","code":"AF"},{"name":"Albania","dial_code":"+355","code":"AL"},{"name":"Algeria","dial_code":"+213","code":"DZ"},{"name":"AmericanSamoa","dial_code":"+1 684","code":"AS"},{"name":"Andorra","dial_code":"+376","code":"AD"},{"name":"Angola","dial_code":"+244","code":"AO"},{"name":"Anguilla","dial_code":"+1 264","code":"AI"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda","dial_code":"+1268","code":"AG"},{"name":"Argentina","dial_code":"+54","code":"AR"},{"name":"Armenia","dial_code":"+374","code":"AM"},{"name":"Aruba","dial_code":"+297","code":"AW"},{"name":"Australia","dial_code":"+61","code":"AU"},{"name":"Austria","dial_code":"+43","code":"AT"},{"name":"Azerbaijan","dial_code":"+994","code":"AZ"},{"name":"Bahamas","dial_code":"+1 242","code":"BS"},{"name":"Bahrain","dial_code":"+973","code":"BH"},{"name":"Bangladesh","dial_code":"+880","code":"BD"},{"name":"Barbados","dial_code":"+1 246","code":"BB"},{"name":"Belarus","dial_code":"+375","code":"BY"},{"name":"Belgium","dial_code":"+32","code":"BE"},{"name":"Belize","dial_code":"+501","code":"BZ"},{"name":"Benin","dial_code":"+229","code":"BJ"},{"name":"Bermuda","dial_code":"+1 441","code":"BM"},{"name":"Bhutan","dial_code":"+975","code":"BT"},{"name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","dial_code":"+387","code":"BA"},{"name":"Botswana","dial_code":"+267","code":"BW"},{"name":"Brazil","dial_code":"+55","code":"BR"},{"name":"British Indian Ocean Territory","dial_code":"+246","code":"IO"},{"name":"Bulgaria","dial_code":"+359","code":"BG"},{"name":"Burkina Faso","dial_code":"+226","code":"BF"},{"name":"Burundi","dial_code":"+257","code":"BI"},{"name":"Cambodia","dial_code":"+855","code":"KH"},{"name":"Cameroon","dial_code":"+237","code":"CM"},{"name":"Canada","dial_code":"+1","code":"CA"},{"name":"Cape Verde","dial_code":"+238","code":"CV"},{"name":"Cayman Islands","dial_code":"+ 345","code":"KY"},{"name":"Central African Republic","dial_code":"+236","code":"CF"},{"name":"Chad","dial_code":"+235","code":"TD"},{"name":"Chile","dial_code":"+56","code":"CL"},{"name":"China","dial_code":"+86","code":"CN"},{"name":"Christmas Island","dial_code":"+61","code":"CX"},{"name":"Colombia","dial_code":"+57","code":"CO"},{"name":"Comoros","dial_code":"+269","code":"KM"},{"name":"Congo","dial_code":"+242","code":"CG"},{"name":"Cook Islands","dial_code":"+682","code":"CK"},{"name":"Costa Rica","dial_code":"+506","code":"CR"},{"name":"Croatia","dial_code":"+385","code":"HR"},{"name":"Cuba","dial_code":"+53","code":"CU"},{"name":"Cyprus","dial_code":"+537","code":"CY"},{"name":"Czech Republic","dial_code":"+420","code":"CZ"},{"name":"Denmark","dial_code":"+45","code":"DK"},{"name":"Djibouti","dial_code":"+253","code":"DJ"},{"name":"Dominica","dial_code":"+1 767","code":"DM"},{"name":"Dominican Republic","dial_code":"+1 849","code":"DO"},{"name":"Ecuador","dial_code":"+593","code":"EC"},{"name":"Egypt","dial_code":"+20","code":"EG"},{"name":"El Salvador","dial_code":"+503","code":"SV"},{"name":"Equatorial Guinea","dial_code":"+240","code":"GQ"},{"name":"Eritrea","dial_code":"+291","code":"ER"},{"name":"Estonia","dial_code":"+372","code":"EE"},{"name":"Ethiopia","dial_code":"+251","code":"ET"},{"name":"Faroe Islands","dial_code":"+298","code":"FO"},{"name":"Fiji","dial_code":"+679","code":"FJ"},{"name":"Finland","dial_code":"+358","code":"FI"},{"name":"France","dial_code":"+33","code":"FR"},{"name":"French Guiana","dial_code":"+594","code":"GF"},{"name":"French Polynesia","dial_code":"+689","code":"PF"},{"name":"Gabon","dial_code":"+241","code":"GA"},{"name":"Gambia","dial_code":"+220","code":"GM"},{"name":"Georgia","dial_code":"+995","code":"GE"},{"name":"Germany","dial_code":"+49","code":"DE"},{"name":"Ghana","dial_code":"+233","code":"GH"},{"name":"Gibraltar","dial_code":"+350","code":"GI"},{"name":"Greece","dial_code":"+30","code":"GR"},{"name":"Greenland","dial_code":"+299","code":"GL"},{"name":"Grenada","dial_code":"+1 473","code":"GD"},{"name":"Guadeloupe","dial_code":"+590","code":"GP"},{"name":"Guam","dial_code":"+1 671","code":"GU"},{"name":"Guatemala","dial_code":"+502","code":"GT"},{"name":"Guinea","dial_code":"+224","code":"GN"},{"name":"Guinea-Bissau","dial_code":"+245","code":"GW"},{"name":"Guyana","dial_code":"+595","code":"GY"},{"name":"Haiti","dial_code":"+509","code":"HT"},{"name":"Honduras","dial_code":"+504","code":"HN"},{"name":"Hungary","dial_code":"+36","code":"HU"},{"name":"Iceland","dial_code":"+354","code":"IS"},{"name":"India","dial_code":"+91","code":"IN"},{"name":"Indonesia","dial_code":"+62","code":"ID"},{"name":"Iraq","dial_code":"+964","code":"IQ"},{"name":"Ireland","dial_code":"+353","code":"IE"},{"name":"Israel","dial_code":"+972","code":"IL"},{"name":"Italy","dial_code":"+39","code":"IT"},{"name":"Jamaica","dial_code":"+1 876","code":"JM"},{"name":"Japan","dial_code":"+81","code":"JP"},{"name":"Jordan","dial_code":"+962","code":"JO"},{"name":"Kazakhstan","dial_code":"+7 7","code":"KZ"},{"name":"Kenya","dial_code":"+254","code":"KE"},{"name":"Kiribati","dial_code":"+686","code":"KI"},{"name":"Kuwait","dial_code":"+965","code":"KW"},{"name":"Kyrgyzstan","dial_code":"+996","code":"KG"},{"name":"Latvia","dial_code":"+371","code":"LV"},{"name":"Lebanon","dial_code":"+961","code":"LB"},{"name":"Lesotho","dial_code":"+266","code":"LS"},{"name":"Liberia","dial_code":"+231","code":"LR"},{"name":"Liechtenstein","dial_code":"+423","code":"LI"},{"name":"Lithuania","dial_code":"+370","code":"LT"},{"name":"Luxembourg","dial_code":"+352","code":"LU"},{"name":"Madagascar","dial_code":"+261","code":"MG"},{"name":"Malawi","dial_code":"+265","code":"MW"},{"name":"Malaysia","dial_code":"+60","code":"MY"},{"name":"Maldives","dial_code":"+960","code":"MV"},{"name":"Mali","dial_code":"+223","code":"ML"},{"name":"Malta","dial_code":"+356","code":"MT"},{"name":"Marshall Islands","dial_code":"+692","code":"MH"},{"name":"Martinique","dial_code":"+596","code":"MQ"},{"name":"Mauritania","dial_code":"+222","code":"MR"},{"name":"Mauritius","dial_code":"+230","code":"MU"},{"name":"Mayotte","dial_code":"+262","code":"YT"},{"name":"Mexico","dial_code":"+52","code":"MX"},{"name":"Monaco","dial_code":"+377","code":"MC"},{"name":"Mongolia","dial_code":"+976","code":"MN"},{"name":"Montenegro","dial_code":"+382","code":"ME"},{"name":"Montserrat","dial_code":"+1664","code":"MS"},{"name":"Morocco","dial_code":"+212","code":"MA"},{"name":"Myanmar","dial_code":"+95","code":"MM"},{"name":"Namibia","dial_code":"+264","code":"NA"},{"name":"Nauru","dial_code":"+674","code":"NR"},{"name":"Nepal","dial_code":"+977","code":"NP"},{"name":"Netherlands","dial_code":"+31","code":"NL"},{"name":"Netherlands Antilles","dial_code":"+599","code":"AN"},{"name":"New Caledonia","dial_code":"+687","code":"NC"},{"name":"New Zealand","dial_code":"+64","code":"NZ"},{"name":"Nicaragua","dial_code":"+505","code":"NI"},{"name":"Niger","dial_code":"+227","code":"NE"},{"name":"Nigeria","dial_code":"+234","code":"NG"},{"name":"Niue","dial_code":"+683","code":"NU"},{"name":"Norfolk Island","dial_code":"+672","code":"NF"},{"name":"Northern Mariana Islands","dial_code":"+1 670","code":"MP"},{"name":"Norway","dial_code":"+47","code":"NO"},{"name":"Oman","dial_code":"+968","code":"OM"},{"name":"Pakistan","dial_code":"+92","code":"PK"},{"name":"Palau","dial_code":"+680","code":"PW"},{"name":"Panama","dial_code":"+507","code":"PA"},{"name":"Papua New Guinea","dial_code":"+675","code":"PG"},{"name":"Paraguay","dial_code":"+595","code":"PY"},{"name":"Peru","dial_code":"+51","code":"PE"},{"name":"Philippines","dial_code":"+63","code":"PH"},{"name":"Poland","dial_code":"+48","code":"PL"},{"name":"Portugal","dial_code":"+351","code":"PT"},{"name":"Puerto Rico","dial_code":"+1 939","code":"PR"},{"name":"Qatar","dial_code":"+974","code":"QA"},{"name":"Romania","dial_code":"+40","code":"RO"},{"name":"Rwanda","dial_code":"+250","code":"RW"},{"name":"Samoa","dial_code":"+685","code":"WS"},{"name":"San Marino","dial_code":"+378","code":"SM"},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","dial_code":"+966","code":"SA"},{"name":"Senegal","dial_code":"+221","code":"SN"},{"name":"Serbia","dial_code":"+381","code":"RS"},{"name":"Seychelles","dial_code":"+248","code":"SC"},{"name":"Sierra Leone","dial_code":"+232","code":"SL"},{"name":"Singapore","dial_code":"+65","code":"SG"},{"name":"Slovakia","dial_code":"+421","code":"SK"},{"name":"Slovenia","dial_code":"+386","code":"SI"},{"name":"Solomon Islands","dial_code":"+677","code":"SB"},{"name":"South Africa","dial_code":"+27","code":"ZA"},{"name":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","dial_code":"+500","code":"GS"},{"name":"Spain","dial_code":"+34","code":"ES"},{"name":"Sri Lanka","dial_code":"+94","code":"LK"},{"name":"Sudan","dial_code":"+249","code":"SD"},{"name":"Suriname","dial_code":"+597","code":"SR"},{"name":"Swaziland","dial_code":"+268","code":"SZ"},{"name":"Sweden","dial_code":"+46","code":"SE"},{"name":"Switzerland","dial_code":"+41","code":"CH"},{"name":"Tajikistan","dial_code":"+992","code":"TJ"},{"name":"Thailand","dial_code":"+66","code":"TH"},{"name":"Togo","dial_code":"+228","code":"TG"},{"name":"Tokelau","dial_code":"+690","code":"TK"},{"name":"Tonga","dial_code":"+676","code":"TO"},{"name":"Trinidad and Tobago","dial_code":"+1 868","code":"TT"},{"name":"Tunisia","dial_code":"+216","code":"TN"},{"name":"Turkey","dial_code":"+90","code":"TR"},{"name":"Turkmenistan","dial_code":"+993","code":"TM"},{"name":"Turks and Caicos Islands","dial_code":"+1 649","code":"TC"},{"name":"Tuvalu","dial_code":"+688","code":"TV"},{"name":"Uganda","dial_code":"+256","code":"UG"},{"name":"Ukraine","dial_code":"+380","code":"UA"},{"name":"United Arab Emirates","dial_code":"+971","code":"AE"},{"name":"United Kingdom","dial_code":"+44","code":"GB"},{"name":"United States","dial_code":"+1","code":"US"},{"name":"Uruguay","dial_code":"+598","code":"UY"},{"name":"Uzbekistan","dial_code":"+998","code":"UZ"},{"name":"Vanuatu","dial_code":"+678","code":"VU"},{"name":"Wallis and Futuna","dial_code":"+681","code":"WF"},{"name":"Yemen","dial_code":"+967","code":"YE"},{"name":"Zambia","dial_code":"+260","code":"ZM"},{"name":"Zimbabwe","dial_code":"+263","code":"ZW"},{"name":"land Islands","dial_code":"","code":"AX"},{"name":"Antarctica","dial_code":null,"code":"AQ"},{"name":"Bolivia, Plurinational State of","dial_code":"+591","code":"BO"},{"name":"Brunei Darussalam","dial_code":"+673","code":"BN"},{"name":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","dial_code":"+61","code":"CC"},{"name":"Congo, The Democratic Republic of the","dial_code":"+243","code":"CD"},{"name":"Cote d'Ivoire","dial_code":"+225","code":"CI"},{"name":"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","dial_code":"+500","code":"FK"},{"name":"Guernsey","dial_code":"+44","code":"GG"},{"name":"Holy See (Vatican City State)","dial_code":"+379","code":"VA"},{"name":"Hong Kong","dial_code":"+852","code":"HK"},{"name":"Iran, Islamic Republic of","dial_code":"+98","code":"IR"},{"name":"Isle of Man","dial_code":"+44","code":"IM"},{"name":"Jersey","dial_code":"+44","code":"JE"},{"name":"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of","dial_code":"+850","code":"KP"},{"name":"Korea, Republic of","dial_code":"+82","code":"KR"},{"name":"Lao People's Democratic Republic","dial_code":"+856","code":"LA"},{"name":"Libyan Arab Jamahiriya","dial_code":"+218","code":"LY"},{"name":"Macao","dial_code":"+853","code":"MO"},{"name":"Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of","dial_code":"+389","code":"MK"},{"name":"Micronesia, Federated States of","dial_code":"+691","code":"FM"},{"name":"Moldova, Republic of","dial_code":"+373","code":"MD"},{"name":"Mozambique","dial_code":"+258","code":"MZ"},{"name":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied","dial_code":"+970","code":"PS"},{"name":"Pitcairn","dial_code":"+872","code":"PN"},{"name":"Réunion","dial_code":"+262","code":"RE"},{"name":"Russia","dial_code":"+7","code":"RU"},{"name":"Saint Barthélemy","dial_code":"+590","code":"BL"},{"name":"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha","dial_code":"+290","code":"SH"},{"name":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","dial_code":"+1 869","code":"KN"},{"name":"Saint Lucia","dial_code":"+1 758","code":"LC"},{"name":"Saint Martin","dial_code":"+590","code":"MF"},{"name":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","dial_code":"+508","code":"PM"},{"name":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","dial_code":"+1 784","code":"VC"},{"name":"Sao Tome and Principe","dial_code":"+239","code":"ST"},{"name":"Somalia","dial_code":"+252","code":"SO"},{"name":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen","dial_code":"+47","code":"SJ"},{"name":"Syrian Arab Republic","dial_code":"+963","code":"SY"},{"name":"Taiwan, Province of China","dial_code":"+886","code":"TW"},{"name":"Tanzania, United Republic of","dial_code":"+255","code":"TZ"},{"name":"Timor-Leste","dial_code":"+670","code":"TL"},{"name":"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of","dial_code":"+58","code":"VE"},{"name":"Viet Nam","dial_code":"+84","code":"VN"},{"name":"Virgin Islands, British","dial_code":"+1 284","code":"VG"},{"name":"Virgin Islands, U.S.","dial_code":"+1 340","code":"VI"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible. If you don't know the country code it's not possible to determine the country just by the local phone number.

Usually, the numbers without country code are located in the same country as the user the phonebook belongs to. So you could just use the users country as a default if there is no country code specified.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution (maybe I'm wrong):
- If it is an online app, you "scan" to find the country code based on the IP address then display the country code.
- or you make the country code field required

Answer (score 0):

I've managed with following 3rd party libraries

```
import { countries } from 'countries-list'
import { getCountry } from 'react-native-localize'
import { getAll } from 'react-native-contacts'


const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<IContact[]>([])

getAll().then((phoneContacts) => {
              setContacts(
                  phoneContacts.flatMap((contact) =>
                      contact.phoneNumbers.map(({ number }) => ({
                          name: contact.givenName + ' ' + contact.familyName,
                          phoneNumber: (number.startsWith('+')
                              ? number
                              : '+' + countries[getCountry()].phone + number.replace(/^0+/, '')
                          ).replace(/[- ]/g, '')
                      }))
                  )
              )
})
```